# Regex to capture part of string that switches between alpha characters and digits at least twice

Tags: regex

My goal is to create a regex to capture a line where some string switches between alpha characters and digits at least twice (but ignoring the filename/extension).

I am trying to find my "weird dynamically generated files".

My current regex captures digit/alpha character changes but also single changes.

I want to only capture a line if there has been multiple number/alpha character changes, since single changes tend to be on purpose (e.g. the name End2EndTest is OK).

How can I improve this regex to capture a pattern only when it's switching, let's say, three times for a string?

Here is my current regex:

```
(:[A-Za-z][A-Za-z\d-_]*\d[A-Za-z\d-_].*?\\|[\d][A-Za-z\d-_]*[A-Za-z][A-Za-z\d-_].*?\\)
```

Data set to match:

```
\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\123xyz123xyz\42abc43abc\App_global.asax.a1b23cd.dll
\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\123xyz123xyz\ab12cd45\App_global.asax.a2cd123.dll
\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1b6123f0\ab12cd34\App_global.asax.kkp9w6zm.dll
\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\42abc43abc\539445c9\App_global.asax.-1bnvx3f.dll
\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\ab12cd34\eb88e642\App_global.asax.fswscrcw.dll
\scope\ScopeWorkingDir\script_7D16668D9F697A13\__ScopeCodeGenEngine__.dll
\scope\ScopeWorkingDir\script_7D16668D9F697A13\__ScopeCodeGen__.dll
\scope\ScopeWorkingDir\script_7D16668D9F697A13\__ScopeCodeGenEngine__.dll
\scope\ScopeWorkingDir\script_7D16668D9F697A13\__ScopeCodeGen__.dll
```

Data set to NOT match:

```
\\bt\\RANDOM\\repo\\out\\retail-amd64\\End2EndTest\\End2EndTest.exe
\\bt\\RANDOM\\repo\\out\\retail-amd64\\HighFive3\\DiskVfy512.exe
```

Comment: Can you add the expected output for the provided lines? That makes it easier for us to understand the problem! And https://regex101.com/ is great for showcasing examples!

Comment: What language or tool are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can an alternation `|` to match either requirement, starting either with a digit, or with a char A-Za-z

If you want to allow more characters in between, you can extend the character class with the allowed chars like `[A-Za-z\d-_]`

Note to put the `-` at the end or escape it `\-`

```
\d[A-Za-z]+\d+[A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z]\d+[A-Za-z]+\d
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d6OWke/1)

If you want to match the whole line:

```
^.*(?:\d[A-Za-z]+\d+[A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z]\d+[A-Za-z]+\d).*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IqrCYM/1)